# JavaScript count Jason data particular value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, count, reduce

this is the data I get from server, the main important is count  "status" part, how many is "alert" , "NOT_COMMUNICATING" or "" (empty means fine)

**Q: How to count data "status", and showing the number that  "alert" is 3, "NOT_COMMUNICATING" is 5 sort of?**

I did study JavaScript  arr.reduce , but array is a little bit tricky that I couldn't figure it out myself, need da hand , thanks

- data json

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "results": 20,
  "ipc_status": [
    {
      "device_id": "1001",
      "name": "E84 IoPC 11",
      "group": "Uk1",
      "ip": "192.168.10.10",
      "port": 5000,
      "ipc_enable": false,
      "ftp_enable": true,
      "status": "",
      "detail": ""
    },
    {
      "device_id": "1002",
      "name": "E3 IoPC 11",
      "group": "Uk1",
      "ip": "192.168.10.10",
      "port": 5006,
      "ipc_enable": true,
      "ftp_enable": true,
      "status": "NOT_COMMUNICATING",
      "detail": "NOT_COMMUNICATING"
    },
    {
      "device_id": "1003",
      "name": "E3 IoPC 15",
      "group": "Uk2",
      "ip": "192.168.10.10",
      "port": 5000,
      "ipc_enable": true,
      "ftp_enable": true,
      "status": "NOT_COMMUNICATING",
      "detail": "NOT_COMMUNICATING"
    },
    {
      "device_id": "1005",
      "name": "E3 IoPC 17",
      "group": "Uk3",
      "ip": "192.168.10.10",
      "port": 5051,
      "ipc_enable": false,
      "ftp_enable": false,
      "status": "",
      "detail": ""
    },
    {
      "device_id": "1010",
      "name": "E3 IoPC 21",
      "group": "Uk3",
      "ip": "192.168.10.10",
      "port": 5010,
      "ipc_enable": false,
      "ftp_enable": false,
      "status": "",
      "detail": ""
    },
    {
      "device_id": "1011",
      "name": "E3 IoPC 23",
      "group": "Uk5",
      "ip": "192.168.10.10",
      "port": 50610,
      "ipc_enable": false,
      "ftp_enable": false,
      "status": "",
      "detail": ""
    },
    {
      "device_id": "1012",
      "name": "E3 IoPC 25",
      "group": "Uk5",
      "ip": "192.168.10.10",
      "port": 50620,
      "ipc_enable": false,
      "ftp_enable": true,
      "status": "",
      "detail": ""
    },
    {
      "device_id": "1019",
      "name": "E3 IoPC 27",
      "group": "Uk5",
      "ip": "192.168.10.10",
      "port": 5069,
      "ipc_enable": false,
      "ftp_enable": true,
      "status": "",
      "detail": ""
    },
    {
      "device_id": "1004",
      "name": "E3 IoPC 29",
      "group": "Uk7",
      "ip": "192.168.10.10",
      "port": 5005,
      "ipc_enable": true,
      "ftp_enable": true,
      "status": "NOT_COMMUNICATING",
      "detail": "NOT_COMMUNICATING"
    },
    {
      "device_id": "test--023",
      "name": "string",
      "group": "Uk7",
      "ip": "string",
      "port": 0,
      "ipc_enable": false,
      "ftp_enable": true,
      "status": "",
      "detail": ""
    },

    {
      "device_id": "test--08773",
      "name": "string",
      "group": "string",
      "ip": "string",
      "port": 0,
      "ipc_enable": false,
      "ftp_enable": true,
      "status": "",
      "detail": ""
    }

  ]
}
```

---

- tried code:
  I tried from database -> api -> json -> count "status"

but mine only count the total of status, *I want different status count*

> ex: 3 "alert" , 5 "NOT_COMMUNICATING"

````
      $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://192.168.10.01:3000/api/all_ipc/status",
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken     // for getting Authorization
        
      },
      success: function(response) {
        var data = response.ipc_status;
        var statusCounts = {};


        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var status = data[i].status;
          if (statusCounts[status]) {
            statusCounts[status]++;
          } else {
            statusCounts[status] = 1;
          }
        }

        console.log("Status Counts:", statusCounts);
      }
    });
  });

```
````

Comment: Does the count include the top-level `"status": "success"`?

Comment: I can't see anything particularly wrong with your code. How does it not work? What result did you expect vs what is the actual result?

Comment: Seems to work fine ~ https://jsfiddle.net/ns4j9o0z/. There are 8 `""` and 5 `"NOT_COMMUNICATING"`

Comment: I think this code helps you: 
var statusCounts = data.reduce(function (acc, cur) {
  var status = cur.status;
  if (acc[status]) {
    acc[status]++;
  } else {
    acc[status] = 1;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

Comment: oh, I did make it correct, my computer compute slow, the actual data are more than 20k, I thought I didn't make it

Answer (score -1):

the tried code is fine, I just didn't print it out

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://192.168.10.01:3000/api/all_ipc/status",
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken     // for getting Authorization
        
      },
      success: function(response) {
        var data = response.ipc_status;
        var statusCounts = {};


        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var status = data[i].status;
          if (statusCounts[status]) {
            statusCounts[status]++;
          } else {
            statusCounts[status] = 1;
          }
        }

        console.log("Status Counts:", statusCounts);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).